# How to navigate to certain tags in BeautifulSoup object?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

Link to url I'm working with: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000106299321002323/0001062993-21-002323.txt

I can access the text/values contained in some tags, but not in others.

Setup (how I got to the BS soup object):

```
new_url = r"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000106299321002323/0001062993-21-002323.txt"
response = requests.get(new_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
```

All of the top level tags (tags that don't have parent tags) seem to be accessible. The child tags that contain values are also accessible.

Here's where I get confused.

```
test = soup.nonDerivativeTable
```

result is `None`

So I cannot navigate to child tags of `nonDerivativeTable` as follows:

```
test = soup.nonDerivativeTable.nonderivativetransaction
```

as that yields an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nonderivativetransaction'`

but I can get there by skipping over `nonDerivativeTable` tag:

```
test = soup.nonderivativetransaction
```

and that works fine. Very confusing as a newb since I accessed a child tag without including the parent tag. If `nonDerivativeTable` had values and tags instead of only tags, would `test = soup.nonDerivativeTable.nonderivativetransaction` have worked?

OK, so now that I can skip over a parent tag that yields `AttributeError`, I try:

```
test = soup.nonderivativetransaction.transactioncoding
```

result looks good:

```
<transactioncoding>
<transactionformtype>4</transactionformtype>
<transactioncode>F</transactioncode>
<equityswapinvolved>0</equityswapinvolved>
</transactioncoding>
```

Drill one level further down:

```
test = soup.nonderivativetransaction.transactioncoding.transactionformtype
```

result looks good:

```
<transactionformtype>4</transactionformtype>
```

but when I try other child tags of same parent:

```
test = soup.nonderivativetransaction.transactioncoding.transactionCode
test = soup.nonderivativetransaction.transactioncoding.equitySwapInvolved
```

result is none:

```
None
None
```

Why can't I access those child tags the same way I accessed another child tag of same parent tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use lxml's [XML parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

For HTML:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
```

For XML (any of the below are equivalent):

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'xml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml-xml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, ['lxml', 'xml'])
```

All of your debugging issues lie in trying to access elements using their case-sensitive names (e.g. `nonDerivativeTable`) but failing to find them because their names have been flattened by the HTML parser (e.g. `nonderivativetable`).

It's perfectly fair to want to access XML elements by their case-specific names because XML (unlike HTML) is a case-sensitive standard.

Comment: XML parsers don't force it to lowercase, so the equivalent here would be `test = soup.nonDerivativeTable` or `test = soup.nonDerivativeTable.transactionCoding`. Specifying `'xml'` is simply lxml's XML parser by the way.

Comment: Thanks! Looking at BeautifulSoup documentation, it shows both `BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml-xml")` and `BeautifulSoup(markup, "xml")`. I guess these are equivalent?

Comment: Yeah, I figured out the xml parser produced a case sensitive soup, which is why I deleted my earlier comment. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yep they're equivalent. No worries

Answer (score 1):

> How to navigate to certain tags in BeautifulSoup object?

Either:

Switch to lower case, with your current syntax:

```
soup.nonderivativetable
```

[Why lowercase?](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

> Because HTML tags and attributes are case-insensitive, all three HTML
> parsers convert tag and attribute names to lowercase. That is, the
> markup  is converted to . If you want to
> preserve mixed-case or uppercase tags and attributes, you’ll need to
> parse the document as XML.

---

Or,

Simply switch to using CSS selectors (perhaps not so ideal given this document):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

new_url = r"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000106299321002323/0001062993-21-002323.txt"
response = requests.get(new_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
soup.select('nonDerivativeTable')
```

---

[lxml](https://lxml.de/) can absolutely be used for xml

> lxml is the most feature-rich and easy-to-use library for processing XML and HTML in the Python language.

---

**Alternative:**

Given the document, extract the actual XML document, then perhaps just work directly with lxml rather than involve BeautifulSoup?